# How to tag users with @mention/@tag in a line group using line bot webhook requests

Tags: php, bots, webhooks, line-api

I cannot find anything in line message API that shows how to tag or mention users in a group that the bot is part of.

`C98a77173e4622xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is the group ID to which I need to send the message to and `U5a4640d93cxxxxxxxxx` is the user I am trying to tag.

I tried something like this:

```
    $data = '{
           "to": "C98a77173e4622xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ,
           "messages": [
                         {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "@{U5a4640d93cxxxxxxxxx}"
                         }
                        ]
            }';
```

This did not work though. I tried all the possible combinations I could think of as the `text` content but everything just gets sent as it is and not getting converted to mentions or tags. I have seen other bots doing this and more actions like removing users from groups, adding users to groups, cancelling invitations and a lot more but none of these message types are mentioned in line Message API. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"Can someone help me..."* as part of a title, isn't a question really.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Then how do I frame the question when a little help is all I need? I have googled and searched through the official documentation and found nothing at all. "Can someone help me.." is the title because I am here expecting some help from someone who has worked on it before. Before you judge the title, please undrstand the context of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody will judge you. I edited your title. That should do the trick. Welcome :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Apologies if it sounded a little harsh. I think I was just too tired trying to get it done. :) Thanks fr the edit.

Answer (score 0):

**There is not this api now.**

You can't tag someone by using line-api.

Comment: Do you know how to go about getting it done?